# Custom receive payments method?

Tags: blockchain.info, receiving

So it's a known problem that blockchain.info's api only allows a gap of 20 unpaid addresses, which sucks and makes their api almost completely worthless. But I was thinking how could I make my own receive payments method with their other not so restricting API's. and I came up with this Idea but I'm not sure if it'll work and I need someone who has expierance with their api to tell if it will. 
so here's my idea:

1. First I create a new address for when a user creates an account
2. I save the new deposit address to the users database entry
3. when the user views the deposit address the user is able to press a refresh    button to check if the transaction is arrived with the needed confirmations.
4. or the client sends a request to the server every 10mins to see if the transaction was sent and confirmed.
5. if it arrived we create a new address and save this as the new deposit address and add the amount sent to the balance.
6. the loop continues without any gap problems!

will this work or am I missing something. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Electrum instead? It's easy enough to integrate with an Electrum wallet, and it has a customisable lookup gap that can be as big as you need it to be.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to do it without having to run a full node.

Comment: Electrum isn't a full node, it's an SPV wallet that only stores block headers (under 100mb). Electrum even runs on Android phones:)

Comment: I'm using NODEJS and I can't seem to find a way to comunicate with it via my NODEJS server. maybe you could give me some links

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin should be treated with the same care as your regular wallet, or even more and you should never store money that you cannot afford to lose with Bitcoin. If you receive payments with Bitcoin , many service providers can convert them